# How to find which Database Roles are associated with a given User?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, roles

In SSMS I have a User `X` and there are `Y`, `Z` and `P` Database Roles available, how may I check what roles are added to a user `X`?

What have I tried:

In SSMS right click on database -> properties -> Permissions and see Explicit tab for a user `X`. I can see Permissions not association between role and the user. The same is for role I'm interested in, I see only permissions for role.

EDIT: Regarding GUI solution, I have no Properties option available for Users nor Roles.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `sys.database_principals` object to find this out:

```
SELECT u.[name] AS [UserName],
       r.[name] AS RoleName 
FROM sys.database_principals u
     JOIN sys.database_role_members drm ON u.principal_id = drm.member_principal_id
     JOIN sys.database_principals r ON  drm.role_principal_id = r.principal_id
WHERE u.[type] IN ('S','U') --SQL User or Windows User
  AND u.[name] = N'X';
```

Answer (score 3):

Through the GUI:

Open the database that you want to check, open Security folder, open Users folder. Here you have a list of defined users for this database.
Right click a user -> properties -> Membership. Here you see the defined roles for this database (custom roles also end up in this list). The user has/is a part of the role if it has an X/mark infront of it.

Through script:

```
SELECT DP1.name AS DatabaseRoleName,   
   isnull (DP2.name, 'No members') AS DatabaseUserName   
 FROM sys.database_role_members AS DRM  
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals AS DP1  
   ON DRM.role_principal_id = DP1.principal_id  
 LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals AS DP2  
   ON DRM.member_principal_id = DP2.principal_id  
WHERE DP1.type = 'R'
--AND DP2.name = 'YourUserName'
ORDER BY DP1.name;
```

Which lists all roles and the users which are a member of it. (Script is from msdn [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-role-members-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)).
This script goes from roles to users. For a specific user fill in the commented parameter. Or just use the [script provided by Larnu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60072842/8258051).

Comment: Regarding GUI solution, I have no Properties option available for Users nor Roles. Please have a look at my edit, thank you.

Comment: @Yoda That is odd. Even on a server where i have basically no server rights, and limited database rights i can still check (only my own) users properties. What SSMS version (and SQL Server version) are you using? The latter shouldn't matter a whole lot, but SSMS version could.

Comment: It's SSMS v17.3 and MSSQL Server 2014.

Comment: @Yoda you could try and update your SSMS to a more recent version (17.3 is several years old). This seems like a GUI problem. Since you were able to access the underlying data, it's unlikely to be a rights issue.

Answer (score 3):

I do it this way:

```
select user_name(role_principal_id)
from sys.database_role_members
where member_principal_id = user_id('your_user');
```